# Xamarin XAML Spinner Styling Issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Spinner I'm trying to give a transparent background. Then on Load it can have a white background. However, no matter what background I give it's always white! Any help is appreciated.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/fertilizer1_amount_unit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#00FF0000"
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/spinneritemdropdown"
        local:MvxBind="SelectedItem ChemigationItem.Fertilizers[0].Unit;Enabled ChemigationItem.IsNew" />
```

SpinnerItemDropDown XAML:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    local:MvxBind="Text Caption" />
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: ,**trying to give a transparent background. Then on Load it can have a white background.** ,change the spinner background:android:background="@android:color/transparent", it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is your `CheckedTextView`'s background property:

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

Should actually be something like this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Wow, so odd to me because we have several other spinners that used the CheckedTextView and they had transparent background. I changed it to what you suggested and it displays properly now. Thanks!